# System bootlooping after TWRP installation

Tags: twrp, boot-loop

I have installed TWRP through Odin, then I booted it. I only seen it, **I haven´t done anything**, just rebooted to the system again, and it got stuck on trying to boot the system.

It's Samsung J7 Prime with Oreo, Odin 3.13 and TWRP-3.2.3-For-Galaxy-J7-Prime.tar

So, what the hell? Why is it not booting? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Can you boot into TWRP? If you can I would try these steps:

- **Boot** into TWRP
- Once TWRP is booted you **first** need to **wipe** your `/data` partition or go into **Wipe > Advanced Wipe** and make sure **Data is ticked** then **swipe to wipe**.
  If this is your **first boot into TWRP:** swipe **Wipe > Format Data** from left to right and follow the instructions displayed onscreen.
- Once it's finished **go back** to  **the home screen** and swipe **Reboot > Recovery** from left to right. TWRP should be able to mount your data partition.
- Now flash the `no-verity-opt-encrypt` zip you downloaded from [this link](https://build.nethunter.com/android-tools/no-verity-opt-encrypt/no-verity-opt-encrypt-6.0.zip), put it on an SD Card and flash it by going to **Install > *%zip location%*** This zip prevents your phone from **bootlooping** since Android Oreo uses **dm-verity** to prevent modification to the system.
- You are (hopefully) now able to reboot to your OS without bootlooping.

  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Joe.

I was in the process that led me to wiping, but I didn't want to wipe, so I tried to do anything else. As soon as I ran out of hope I can preserve the data, I wiped it. And it was back to normal.

Comment: wipe is just necessary for fixing problems with decryption - if your twrp does mount your data partition successfully, you can continue with installing no-verity.zip without wiping data